# Report all files less or = to 1KB

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an alert that will look at directories and email a listing of all files that are 1kb or less.  Currently it is sending one email for every file.  I want the offending files to be in one email.

```
$date= Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$path= "c:\test\$date"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse
$body = "These files are too small."
$body += "<table><tr><td><b>Filename</b></td></tr>";
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.Length -lt 1kb) {
        $body += "<tr><td>" + $($file.Name) + "</td></tr>"
    }
};
$body += "</table>"
foreach ($item in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path)) {  
    $a=get-item($item)
    if ($a.Length -lt 1kb) {
        Send-MailMessage -From noreply@email.com -To person@email.com -Subject "Files small" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 0.0.0.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping twice. Simply remove the loop around `Send-MailMessage`:

```
$body += "<table><tr><td><b>Filename</b></td></tr>"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.Length -lt 1kb) {
        $body += "<tr><td>" + $($file.Name) + "</td></tr>"
    }
}
$body += "</table>"

Send-MailMessage -From noreply@email.com -To person@email.com -Subject "Files small" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 0.0.0.0
```

You can add a flag variable to indicate whether files were found or not:

```
$body += "<table><tr><td><b>Filename</b></td></tr>"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.Length -lt 1kb) {
        $fileFound = $true
        $body += "<tr><td>" + $($file.Name) + "</td></tr>"
    }
}
$body += "</table>"

if ($fileFound) {
    Send-MailMessage -From noreply@email.com -To person@email.com -Subject "Files small" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 0.0.0.0
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I also was able to accomplish by adding this:  $submitted = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? {$_.Length -lt 1kb}
if(@($submitted).Count -eq 0)